# Documenting Sinatra routes for extensions (Yard::Sinatra doesn't work)

Tags: sinatra, yard

I am writing a moderate-sized Sinatra app that I break into extensions, placed in ./lib/extensions/. I want to document each route, but Yard::Sinatra only documents the routes defined in the main application.rb file. Can I configure Yard::Sinatra to do something or do I have to write my own plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look into [Cachafla's YARD::Sinatra version](https://github.com/cachafla/yard-sinatra/) of the gem: `gem install cachafla-yard-sinatra`